# Hypernyms and Hyponyms

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

What is the difference between hypernyms and hyponyms?
Is defend hypernym to endorse?
Similarly what about permit,allow and consent?

I'm confused in both of these things,Is there anyone who clear to me what is actually difference between these two?

Comment: I think you are confusing hyponymy/hypernymy with synonyms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I learned that these two words existed just now by reading your post (learn something new every day), but here's the difference between the two:

*Hyponym:* a more "drilled down" topic from the original word

*Hypernym:* a generic word that can apply to the original word and others (similar to a category)

Here's the example Wikipedia gives:

> Pigeon, crow, eagle and seagull are all hyponyms of bird (their hypernym); which, in turn, is a hyponym of animal.

Pigeon, crow, and eagle are all types of birds. "Bird" is their hypernym as it's the category they fit into. Similarly, "bird" fits into the category of "animal".

To go the other way, starting with "bird", since pigeon, crow, and eagle are types of birds, they are "bird"s hyponym.

*Hyper* is going up, *hypo* is going down.

Answer (score 1):

[Hyponymy and hypernymy on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyponymy_and_hypernymy).

A **hypo**nym is:

> A more specific term; a subordinate grouping word or phrase.

A **hyper**nym is:

> A word or phrase whose referents form a set including as a subset the referents of a subordinate term.

So, `spoon` would be a hyponym of `cutlery`. `Cutlery` is a hypernym of `spoon`, `fork` and `kitchen knife`.

Another example: `dog` is a hyponym of `animal`.

---

> Similarly what about permit,allow and consent?

I'd say those are [synonyms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synonym).